# Can't join chat for a very long time already

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, login

I have this bug for quite some time now, but I never had the time to ask it somewhere. but when I try to go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com I automatically get this message:
[image: Error]

Unfortunately, when I press on `click here` I got redirected to the desired chatbox, but I still am not connected.
[image]

Also, quite often I get this message as well:
[image]

Is my account bugged? Did someone else have this issue before?

Comment: There's no history of multiple accounts, merged accounts, deleted accounts, suspensions, etc.?

Comment: I think there is, is it relevant? I can recall that I created a account a few years ago, and then I recalled I had already one, so I had 2 accounts and asked to merge them.

Comment: It could be. There may no longer be a chat account associated with your account something something mumble mumble. That would require someone with a diamond to look into. So sit back and wait :D

Comment: I might even have deleted my stackoverflow account when I quit programming. However, I remained quite active in mechanics.stackexchange, But hey, thanks for clearing up. I'll wait:)

Comment: It seems [this is your chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/144552/). However, the current parent user is directed to your (deleted?) SO account. I don't know if it will help, but can you change the parent user to another site first?

Comment: @Elephant Could you please tell me how to do that?:)

Comment: I assume if you can log in to the chat server, then there's `[change]` link beside the parent user, but if you can't access it, then I think the issue is deeper than this and need SE devs to fix it.

Comment: I can see the change button, also changed it to stackoverflow -> MiaSan

Comment: Now, can you join any SO chat room?

Comment: No, maybe I have to wait a little? if you click on your link you can see it has changed

Comment: Account deletion/merge etc and chat profiles are total mess to this day, i.e. deleting/merging account cause the chat profile to be ruined for good. SE developer has to step in and manually fix your chat profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, I'll wait patiently then. Or do I have to send an email to the staff?

Comment: @MiaSan email is one way, quicker way is asking a dev in the Tavern to kindly do it, usually Adam is doing those things, think he's pingable in there.

Comment: Looking into it, one sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it a go now, you should be able to access chat again.

Long story short, when you deleted your old Stack Overflow profile, we didn't yet remove chat profiles at the same time... So when you visited chat with your current profile, there was a conflict on account id.